# Database how to lock a table ONLY for specific INSERT with specific values?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, concurrency, locking

is there a manner to lock a table specifying that only the insert with a specific value should be blocked?
For example I have the table "task" and the table "subtask" I need an operation that when the task is closed also the subtasks pertaining to it and still open should be closed. So I would like to:

1. Start a transaction
2. Lock the table subtask **but only preventing that an insert with a given task id can be performed**
3. Close all the subtask
4. Close the task using the optimistic lock (if the task version changed do a rollback of all)
5. Commit the transaction

Is it possible to do what I described in step 2? If not (or if there is a better way) how can I obtain a safe concurrency on this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create the row yourself! But you can delete it at the end of the transaction. Here's how it goes

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ....
AS $$

    BEGIN

       INSERT INTO subtasks VALUE(pk, ...) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
       GET DIAGNOSTICS inserted = ROW_COUNT

       if inserted THEN
           DELETE from subtasks where pk = id
       endif;
    COMMIT;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that in the above code [INSERT ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) does not actually make any changes to the existing data. It will return the number of rows changed. If no rows were changed that inserted variable will hold zero.

What's happening here is that having inserted a record with in your transaction, any other connection will not be able to save the same record. You can confirm this for your self by opening to connections to the database with psql. Then do

```
begin;
   insert ...

   # just wait here
commit;
```

and in the other one, try the same insert, you will see that it hangs. Whether the insert suceeds or fails depends on whether you commit or rollback in the first psql connection.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but I'm not sure that it works in my case (but maybe I misunderstood it). Why it should prevent to add a subtask to a given task?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to use ON CONFLICT on a NON unique column. 
In this case the column subtask(taskId) is not unique because many subtask can have the same task as parent.
Otherwhise using ON CONFLICT on the pk column of subtask (ie subtask(subtaskId) ) should not work because the second thread could insert a subtask with a different id respect the id of the subtask inserted by the first subtask so it would be not in conflict

Comment: Well this answer is valid based on the information that you have originally provided. The fact that you do not have a unique index was not mentioned. As such please be so kind as to mark the answer as correct and post a new one with __full information__

Answer (score 0):

You can't lock a table for a specific value but in your case this solution would apply: create a trigger on insert in subtasks and in this trigger check if the corespondent task is closed. If the task is closed than do not allow the insert.

Another trigger on tasks will close all corespondent subtask as soon as the task is closed.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution can't be applied in my case because if the insert (thread B) occurs when thread A closed all the subtasks but have not closed the main task it causes an inconsistency. 
BTW if it is not possible the only solution here seems to be lock the entire subtask table. Tnx

Comment: I dond't  think this problem should exist because postgres functions are single transactions. The trigger on tasks will run as a single transaction and you can't have a task closed and the corespondent subtasks opened.